# setObject doesn't work within one of the classes

Tags: ios, nsmutabledictionary, writetofile

I'm trying to make a 'saveState' method with implementation (in blablabla.m):

```
-(void)saveState {
NSString *masterCode = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:first];
masterCode = [masterCode stringByAppendingString:second];
masterCode = [masterCode stringByAppendingString:third];
masterCode = [masterCode stringByAppendingString:fourth];
NSLog(@"master passcode - %@", masterCode);

NSString *plistPath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"timeLimiterMasterCode.plist"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:plistPath contents:nil attributes:nil];
}

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) {
    NSLog(@"file exists, %@", plistPath);
}

NSMutableDictionary *plistCode = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

[plistCode setObject:masterCode forKey:@"MasterCode"];

NSLog(@"whole plist - %@", plistCode);

[plistCode writeToFile:plistPath atomically: YES];

NSLog(@"master passcode from file - %@", [plistCode objectForKey:@"MasterCode"]);

}
```

masterCode is not nill, in blablabla.h file I'm using protocol UIApplicationDelegate, "file exists" but application returns: 
2013-01-29 12:19:50.496 timeLimiter[916:907] whole plist - (null)
2013-01-29 12:19:50.500 timeLimiter[916:907] master passcode from file - (null)

Besides in viewController (.m, .h) I use another plist and write method and the work correctly.

I found that [plistCode setObject:masterCode forKey:@"MasterCode"] is hill. I've tried to replace 'masterCode' with @"test" but it did no sense.

Could you solve my issue? Please?

Comment: Is your file located at temporary directory?

Comment: yes, according to NSTemporaryDirectory(): /private/var/mobile/Applications/DD7F0E82-5718-4E9A-8048-01F16BDC7681/tmp/timeLimiterMasterCode.plist

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution but don't know the explanation. The solutions is to replace

```
NSMutableDictionary *plistCode = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath]
```

with

```
NSMutableDictionary *newPlistCode = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init].
```

After that method works great! Thanks to init)